# Java exception stacktrace has "$8", what does this mean?

Tags: java, exception

So this is not the first time I see exception messages but I'm curious as to what the special characters mean in the stacktrace. I'm using Java in Android and this exception shows a `$8` right next to the class name then the method name where the exception took place.

I was researching but was not able to find any information on what it means. Below is the stacktrace and the `$8` I'm referring to.

```
java.lang.Exception: Error, server response 400
    at cb.cheneytracker.service.callers.ServerCaller$8.onResponse(ServerCaller.java:858)
    at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:83)
```

So to be more precise, since i'm getting down-voted for "needs detail or clarity". What does `$` mean in the exception stack trace above. I see `$8` and `$1$1`, what do these mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the auto generated name for anonymous class, it is 8 because there are at least 8 anonymous class in the container class, you can see it in action here:

```java
    interface Test {
        void doSomething();
    }
    public static Test createTest() {
        return new Test() {
            @Override
            public void doSomething() {
                System.out.println("I'm busy...");
            }
        };
    }
    public static Test createAnotherTest() {
        return new Test() {
            @Override
            public void doSomething() {
                System.out.println("Ok");
            }
        };
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = createTest();
        System.out.println(t.getClass().getName());

        t = createAnotherTest();
        System.out.println(t.getClass().getName());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I know, it is a name of anonymous class that compiler automatically generated

Comment: I figured something like this was at play but I can't find references to this anywhere. Maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing online?

Comment: @Dayan The Java Language Specification in section 3.8 allows a dollar sign as part of an identifier, but says it should only be used in mechanically generated code. The original specification for anonymous inner classes says that $ is used in generating the name of the inner class. Search for 'dollar' in this document: [*Inner Classes Specification*](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/JLS/innerclasses.pdf)